# Why does gcc need the definition of unused _Generic values?

Tags: c, gcc

Consider this code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <float.h> //uncomment so it can be compiled

#define GETMAX(variable) _Generic        \
  (                                      \
    (variable)                           \
    , bool                : 1            \
    , char                : CHAR_MAX     \
    , unsigned char       : UCHAR_MAX    \
    , signed   char       : SCHAR_MAX    \
    , unsigned short      : USHRT_MAX    \
    , signed   short      : SHRT_MAX     \
    , unsigned int        : UINT_MAX     \
    , signed   int        : INT_MAX      \
    , unsigned long       : ULONG_MAX    \
    , signed   long       : LONG_MAX     \
    , unsigned long long  : ULLONG_MAX   \
    , signed   long long  : LLONG_MAX    \
    , float               : FLT_MAX      \
    , double              : DBL_MAX      \
    , long double         : LDBL_MAX     \
  )

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  (void)argv;
  uint_fast8_t a;
  if( argc>GETMAX(a) )
    { printf("argc too big\n"); }
  else
    { printf("argc small enough\n"); }
  return 0;
}
```

It will not compile with gcc nor clang (don't know about other compilers), gcc complains with `error: ‘FLT_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function) ...` (even without any warning flags) But why? i use the `GETMAX` with a integer, the value of `FLT_MAX` is irrelevant for that, on my machine, only `UCHAR_MAX` should be needed. The line `if( argc>GETMAX(a) )` should turn into a equivalent of `if( argc>UCHAR_MAX )` (after compiling, `FLT_MAX` is still there after the preprocessor), making all other limits irrelevant.

The fix is easy, just add `#include <float.h>`, the question is about why this is the way it is.

Comment: @interjay But wouldn't that only justify a warning, but not a error?

Comment: @interjay: `_Generic` is part of the main C grammar, not preprocessing. When it is being analyzed, preprocessing for anything in it is complete, and `FLT_MAX` is an identifier. Whether it could have been a macro in preprocessing is irrelevant.

Comment: @interjay After the preprocessing is done, this will not work anymore. So the compiler could assume it doesn't affect the function and compile it (of course, a warning would be wise). The compiler has all the data needed. A c compiler will tolerate many other things and assume unknown things (for example implicit function declarations).

Comment: Similarly to this problem, all _Generic execution paths must be valid after the pre-processor is done. Given `void f_int (int*);` then this is invalid: `#define func(x) _Generic((x), int: f_int(&(x)), float: f_float (&(x)) )`. Because even if you call the macro as `func(my_int)`, `f_float(&my_int)` must still be valid code and in case that function takes a `float*` parameter, it is not.

Comment: You can solve either problem by wrapping the constant inside a getter function. `float: FLT_MAX` -> `float: flt_max()` then `static float flt_max (void) { return FLT_MAX; }`. A sane compiler will inline all of those, so no performance loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C expects all identifiers used in expressions to be declared.<sup>1</sup> While it might be possible to redesign the language to ignore undeclared identifiers in certain places, requiring declarations helps avoid bugs.

There are other places where an unknown identifier might be ignored. For example, consider:

```
int foo(void)
{
    return 1 || x;
}
```

The value of `1 || x` is 1 regardless of what value `x` has. However, if `typedef int x;` were in the code before this, it would be an error, because the right operand of `||` must be a grammatical *logical-AND-expression*, and a type is not an expression. So, with `x` undeclared, the compiler cannot check whether `1 || x` is a valid expression as defined by the rules of the C standard.

Another example is `int a[3]; return sizeof a[x];`, which would, if accepted, return the size of an `int` regardless of `x`. In this, the C standard says `x` is not evaluated. Yet it must be declared. Another example is `return 0; x;`. Here, there is no way for program control to reach `x`, so it is never evaluated. Yet it must be declared.

Similarly, in `_Generic`, the grammatical entity after a `:` must be an *assignment-expression*, and the compiler cannot check that unless the identifiers in it are declared.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> In the past, an identifier used as a function designator in a call would be automatically assumed to be a function. This has been removed from the C standard.

Comment: I am sure this is the correct answer. But nevertheless, I understand the interrogation. Because in `1||x` it is dynamic consideration that makes `x` useless (dynamic consideration that any decent compiler would solve statically. But yet, that is optimization: strictly speaking, `1||x` means that dynamically, value of `1` is tested, and if 0, then value of x is the value of the expression). Whereas `_Generic` (which, btw, I learn about only now, with this question, so nothing I say must be interpreted as authoritative. I am just trying to understand), is static as I understand it.

Comment: I mean, it is not just optimization. Seeing `int a; _Generic(a,int:1,float:y)` the compiler should statically decide to compile just `1` code, not `y`. So, almost like a `#if 1` `1` `#else` `y` `#endif`.

Comment: @chrslg: The problem is fundamentally in grammatical analysis, so optimization is not very relevant. If you want examples where an expression is known not to be evaluated by type and grammar information alone, not value, then consider `int a[3]; sizeof a[x];` or `goto y; x; y: ;`. Both of these will fail to compile because `x` is not declared even though `x` would never be evaluated and could never affect program behavior, as long as it resolved to some expression, the same as `FLT_MAX` in your `_Generic`. C simply requires identifiers to be declared.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation! I was trying to find a `sizeof` analogy myself, since indeed, it is not a preprocessor code, even if statically evaluated, like `_Generic`, if I understood correctly. My `#if ...` example remove the code before it is even compiled. What I had in mind for `sizeof` is the classical `int *x; sizeof(*x);`, in which it doesn't matter that `*x` is faulty. But the difference is that `*x` is syntaxically correct, so it was not a good analogy. Yours, `int a[x]` is one. And indeed, in that analogy, compilation also fails.

Comment: So, if I try to rephrase what I understand from your example: "static functions" (term is ambiguous; I don't mean function declared `static`, but function that are evaluated statically — not just because the compiler can do it, as an optimization, but because it must: a dynamic evaluation would not be possible, since there isn't any type information at runtime), such as `_Generic` or `sizeof` are not the same thing as a preprocessor macro: this is still C code, and therefore must comply with C language (where as  iin `#if 0 blabla #endif`, nothings says that `blabla` has to be legal C code).

Comment: (And yes, I know they are keywords, not functions. "static functions" is just the word I use to convey the fact that it does something statically)

Comment: @chris `_Generic` and `sizeof` are not functions, they are operators. "My `#if ...` example remove the code before it is even compiled." Simply speaking, every line that starts with a `#` is a preprocessor directive that will be done why preprocessing, compiling comes after that. `blabla` is still limited, if it is `/*` the `#endif` will be without a effect.